# How to separate and already established icloud account

Tags: icloud

How do I separate my daughter's Apple ID and iCloud account from my own and still be able to keep a payment plan that covers 2 phones? I read that this is possible but can't seem to set up the new account name or passwords on either  phone. What steps do I need to take?

Thanks for your assistance.
G.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide a more complete answer.

First of all, you should create an Apple ID (iCloud account) for your daughter.

Once it's done, you can activate on **your** phone what Apple calls `Family Sharing`. This will make you the family owner. You can find it in your `Settings` app. [Here is the documentation to set it up](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088).

Once done, you just have to pair her account through **her** phone to yours.

This feature will allow you to share bought application or media and give you additional features such as location... But you will also be able to share the payment methods with control options ("need to ask for authorisation before buying anything"...).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Family Sharing if you want to share purchases from the App Store and iTunes Store (in iCloud section of settings) while keeping accounts separate.